# MySQL No. of connections count

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

I have a medium sized database (7 GB) with around 200 concurrent users. i am getting some database lag issues, suddenly my node-mysql client freezes during `select`s and `insert`s.

as a process of troubleshooting i checked `SHOW STATUS` on the DB, everything seemed to be okay but just the **Connections** attribute has **262050**.

want to understand if this number is okay or if the figure is exorbitant?

Comment: This look more like question for https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Exorbitant. Definitely.

Find a machine running your node app, and watch its logs and/or error outputs while you stop and restart the MySQL server.

Hopefully the node app will chatter away telling you that lots of connections were closed as you stop the MySQL server.

This looks like a connection leak. You probably have some sort of problem with your node connection pooling, or maybe with releasing connections after your node app uses then.